# Panda read_excel() gives incorrect date value

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have abc.xlsb file having column name "Reporting Date". It is having values "16-Aug-21". I am trying to convert abc.xlsb to a CSV file. But I am getting random value for date "44424"

```
import pandas as pd 
xls = pd.ExcelFile('abc.xlsb') 
df = pd.read_excel(xls, 'xyz_sheetname') 
print(df['Reporting Date'])
```

Output :

```
44424
```

Expected output :

```
16-Aug-21
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

44424 represents the number of days passed since 12/31/1899

For example:

```
1 = 31 Dec 1899
2 = 1 Jan 1900
3 = 2 Jan 1900
```

So, 44424 would be exactly 16 Aug 2021 as expected.

You can use this logic on pandas to get the actual date before exporting into csv.

You might want to check this: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2019/08/13/google-sheets-change-date-format/

This should work:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": [1,2,3,4, 44424]})
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: timedelta(x) + datetime(1899,12,30))

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks @Emmanuel Murairi , could you please help me to get expected date ?

Comment: I can't change source file. I want to do it using python.

Comment: I have updated the response to include a potential solution

Comment: @Tushar you shouldn't need to change the source file